# kernel parameter init=/bin/bash not working? (RHEL7, RHCSA test)

Tags: centos, terminal, rhel, init

I took the RHCSA test a couple of weeks ago, which is a lab/hands-on test. The first step is to gain root access of the VM. Usually (and this works okay on my PC's VirtualBox CentOS 7 VM) I do this by adding kernel parameter `init=/bin/bash rw`. But on the test's VM this did not really work. After the kernel dropped me to root password, the text that I typed did not echo to the terminal even after I issued `reset`. Changing password using `passwd` proved to be impossible because the terminal seems to eat some of my keystrokes. I had to resort to using kernel parameter `rd.break`. The question is why, especially the weird terminal behavior?

Comment: I think it is related to the initrd, it is loading something that is broken the terminal.... Not intentional....

Comment: How do you enter a kernel parameter in Virtualbox? Through Grub by holding shift during boot?

Comment: I believe its because it should be `rw init=/bin/bash`. The order is backwards maybe?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer that you are looking for, but just to mention that, you can erase the password from your `/etc/shadow` file once you have added your `init=/bin/sh`(I prefer sh because is likely to be on every *nix environment because of historical reasons, it could even be a symlink to bash, but you get the point.

once in your shell, always remount your drive with `mount -n -o remount,rw /` and go to your `/etc/shadow` file. You should read something like:

```
root:123l4kj'0978dsfgasfli132094187234aposdiuf987:14414:0:99999:7:::
.....
```

erase all the encrypted string and leave it like:

```
root::14414:0:99999:7::
```

After that you can reset your VM and the next time you boot you log with **root** and **no password**

PS. [here](https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/recover-root-grub) is a tutorial about this

Comment: Well, the problem is the terminal's input got screwed up and ate many keystrokes. If I couldn't successfully type "passwd" then enter the new password twice successfully (the terminal seemed to eat the first character of every line, and some characters in between, seemingly randomly, and I *couldn't* turn on echo), what hope I have typing more complex stuffs? :) I guess I can use `sed` or `perl` to erase the field in a one-liner... But anyway, the question is not about how to actually change the root password, but why using "init=/bin/bash" makes the terminal screwy on RHEL 7.3?

Answer (score 0):

```
init=/bin/bash rw
```

But this "rw", what is it doing there? Will it not be interpreted as argument to bash? First root gets mounted, then /bin/bash can be started.